# Debugging FCM unreceived data messages

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I recently looked at the Firebase FCM console for the first time, and got surprised to see we send data messages. I was even more surprised to see that they don't seem to be received!

[image: data messages graph]

I activated syncing data to BigQuery, and played around with the data a bit (data available for just last few days, that's why the numbers are low compared to the graph above):

```
SELECT event, COUNT(*) FROM [firebase_messaging.data] WHERE message_type = 'DATA_MESSAGE' GROUP BY event;
```

[image: types of events of data messages]

As you can see above, none seems to have been delivered.

Also, here's some raw BigQuery data:

[image]

**Questions:**

1) How can I figure out where these data messages are actually being sent? As far as I can see in our code, we only send notification messages. Maybe it's a 3rd party service? Maybe we *do* send it ourselves but I missed?

2) Related to the above: is there a way I can look into payload of data messages? BigQuery (as can be seen in the above screenshot) does not show this.

3) What are some possible reasons why these data messages aren't being received?

Comment: Do you have access to your backend which is using the firebase fcm sdk to send notifications?

Comment: Yes I do. But we also we use some 3rd party services (like Iterable, perhaps some others) that can send too.